# Странное поведение limit X offset Y в запросах

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Добрый день.

Есть таблица с двумя полями, одно из них ключ.
Скрипт создания таблицы и заполнения можно взять [здесь](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/indapublic/689f00dbdcf8c75f5557f28b29c50933/raw/efbcbed1212e1e9fac60324ea69600087c662a83/test.sql)

Выполняю запрос, который сравнивает две порции таблицы для пагинации:

```
select
  *
from
  (
    select distinct id, created_at from aaa order by created_at desc limit 5 offset 0
  ) a,
  (
    select distinct id, created_at from aaa order by created_at desc limit 5 offset 5
  ) b
where a.id = b.id
```

Логично предположить, что не должно оказаться одинаковых записей в обоих подзапросах?

Однако mysql возвращает три таких записи, а Mariadb возвращает одну.

> mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine
>   wrapper
>   mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.6-MariaDB, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using
>   readline 5.1

Если у таблицы удалить первичный ключ, тогда повторяющиеся записи исчезнут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного теории: Если порядок следования записей не определен однозначно, SQL *имеет право* применять любой порядок, который ему нравится. В данном случае вы просите SQL отсортировать данные по полю created_at. При этом в БД есть много записей с одинаковым created_at. Например, указанный order определяет такой порядок сортировки:

```
Дата                  ID
2017-06-09 15-08-26   4
2017-06-09 15-08-25   3
2017-06-09 15-08-25   2
2017-06-09 15-08-25   1
```

У трех записей дата создания одинакова, следовательно при сортировке по дате такой порядок так же полностью удовлетворяет условию:

```
Дата                  ID
2017-06-09 15-08-26   4
2017-06-09 15-08-25   2
2017-06-09 15-08-25   1
2017-06-09 15-08-25   3
```

А теперь рассмотрим план выполнения запроса (я задал limit 10):

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |   10 | NULL           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 108     | a.id |    2 | NULL           |
|  3 | DERIVED     | aaa        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 3019 | Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | aaa        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 3019 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

Из него следует, что таблицу из первого подзапроса MySQL берет целиком из области данных и сортирует. По второму подзапросу он принимает решение подобрать подходящие записи по ID из первой таблицы, т.е. фактически заранее выполнить объединение `a.id=b.id`, таким образом данные с диска он получает не в том порядке как они лежат в области данных, а выдергивая по одной на основании первичного ключа. После чего и эту выборку он сортирует. Но так как изначальный порядок записей был другим, то сортировка в пределах одной даты создания выдает другой порядок следования id. После этого MySQL наконец применяет к полученным данным `offset` и `limit`. И фактически оказывается, что лимиты были применены к разным наборам данных (отсортированным в разном порядке), что и влечет за собой одинаковые id на выходе после применения лимита.

В случае отсутствия первичного ключа на таблице у оптимизатора не остается другого выбора как только получать таблицу целиком из области данных. Поэтому оба набора при применении limit оказываются одинаковы и запрос уже не находит одинаковых id.

Показанное в Вашем вопросе отлично демонстрирует, на сколько важно однозначно определять порядок сортировки при использовании операции `limit`. Добавление поля ID в предложение `order by` полностью устраняет проблему, SQL в таком случае гарантирует одинаковый порядок записей и следовательно срез получаемый лимитом.

Comment: Просто браво, отлично написано. Жалко, что один могу поставить только один плюс. Добавление ID в сортировку мне не подходит. Видимо, единственный вариант - поменять даты создания

Comment: @indapublic Кстати, создание индекса по полю created_at так же решает проблему, но не гарантированно, потому что нельзя полагаться на конкретный план выполнения, станет больше данных, поменяется версия БД, просто не та фаза луны окажется и оптимизатор может пойти по другому пути. Зато при правильном пути этот индекс должен ускорить работу, так как оптимизатору не надо будет каждый раз сортировать таблицу заново, он пойдет по индексу

Comment: Черт, я упустил, что на таблице нет индекса в этом проекте. Большое спасибо